# Como puedo desde un boton que esta en un fragment a otro que están conectados mediante viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Tengo definidos un Fragment "B" con una Button, cuando clico este boton quiero llamar a el Fragment "A" pasando le información por parámetro.

Estoy utilizando este ejemplo:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es

Gracias !

Comment: que desde un fragment puede operar con otro fragment la mejor forma es hacerlo des de la actividad que han sido llamados, con getActivity() puedes aceder desde los fragments hijos.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de llamar un fragment des de otro fragment es hacerlo mediante su padre que es la Activity que han sido llamados, por ejemplo tienes un método de carga de fragments

`public void cargarFragment(nuevo_fragmento)`

Des de un fragmento puedes lanzar la función con.

`((MainActivity)getActivity()).cargarFragment(nuevo_fragmento);`

Para pasar parámetros a los fragmentos los fragmentos debe tener `newInstance` y computar los parámetros en el, un pequeño ejemplo.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    private TextView mNameTextView;
    private TextView mAgeTextView;

    public static MyFragment newInstance(String name, int age) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", name);
        bundle.putInt("age", age);
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    private void readBundle(Bundle bundle) {
        if (bundle != null) {
            name = bundle.getString("name");
            age = bundle.getInt("age");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
        mNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        mAgeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ageTextView);

        readBundle(getArguments());

        mNameTextView.setText(String.format("Name: %s", name));
        mAgeTextView.setText(String.format("Age: %d", age));

        return view;
    }

}
```

Instanciar un fragmento con parámetros

`new MyFragment.newInstance("pedro",20);`

Es cuestión de adaptar ese código a tus necesidades.

Comment: Ok , gracias entiendo que únicamente con ((MainActivity)getActivity()) puedo acceder a los metodos del MainActivity.